# How can time spent in asynchronous generators be measured?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, generator

I want to measure a time spent by generator (time blocking main loop).

Lets say that I have two following generators:

```
async def run():
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        yield i
    return

async def walk():
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0.3)
        yield i
    return
```

I want to measure that `run` spent around `0.0s` per iteration, while `walk` used at least `0.3s`.

I wanted to use something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028924/how-to-measure-time-spent-in-blocking-code-while-using-asyncio-in-python), but wasn't able to make it work for me.

Clarification:

I want to exclude the time spent in any `await` section. If for any reason coroutine is halted, then I don't want to take this time into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So - one thing (a bit though) is to measure times in regular co-routines - I got it going with a decorator.

However, when you go a step ahead into async-generators, it is another beast - I am still trying to figure it out -  it is a mix of public-exposed async-iterator methods (`__anext__`, `asend`, etc...) with traditional iterator methods in the objects returned, I could not yet figure out (I've just opened PEP 525 to see if I can make sense of it).

As for regular co-routines, there is a gotcha: if you make an awaitable class (my decorator), asyncio will demand its `__await__` method returns something with a `__next__` method, which will be called. But native Python co-routines have no `__next__`: asyncio calls `send()` on those - so I had to make this "transpose" in order to be able to measure the time (in co-routines).

```
import asyncio
import time


class ProfileCoro:
    def __init__(self, corofunc):
        self.corofunc = corofunc

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        # WARNING: not parallel execution-safe: fix by
        # keeping "self.ellapsed" in a proper contextvar
        self.ellapsed = 0
        self.coro = self.corofunc(*args, **kw)
        return self

    def __await__(self):
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.send(None)

    def throw(self, exc):
        print(f"Arghh!, got an {exc}")
        self.coro.throw(exc)

    def send(self, arg):
        start = time.monotonic()
        try:
            result = self.coro.send(arg)
        except StopIteration:
            duration = time.monotonic() - start
            self.ellapsed += duration
            print(f"Ellapsed time in execution of {self.corofunc.__name__}: {self.ellapsed:.05f}s")
            raise
        duration = time.monotonic() - start
        self.ellapsed += duration
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<ProfileCoro wrapper for {self.corofunc}>"

@ProfileCoro
async def run():
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        # yield i
    return 1

@ProfileCoro
async def walk():
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0.3)
        #yield i
    return 3


async def main():
    await run()
    await walk()
    return

asyncio.run(main())
```

To *maybe* be continued, if I can figure out how to wrap the async generators.

(I think most existing profiling tools use the tooling available in the language for debuggers and tracing (enabled with `sys.settrace()` : everything is just "visible" in a callback for them, and no worries about wrapping all the inner the calls made by the async machinery and the asyncio loop)

...
So, here is the code instrumented to also catch the time in async-generators.

It will get the happy path - if there are complicated awaitable classes, implementing or making use of `asend`, `athrow`, this won't do - but for a simple async generator function plugget to an `async for` statement it now works:

DISCLAIMER: there might be unused code, and even unused states in the code bellow - I went back and forth quite a bit to get it working (a lot of it because I had not attempted to the fact `__anext__` had to be async itself). Nonetheless here it go:

```
import asyncio
import time

from functools import wraps


async def _a():
    yield 1

async_generator_asend_type = type(_a().__anext__())


class ProfileCoro:
    def __init__(self, corofunc):
        self.corofunc = corofunc
        self.measures = 0

    def measure_ellapsed(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
            self.measures += 1
            if self.measures > 1:
                try:
                    return func(self, *args, **kw)
                finally:
                    self.measures -= 1
            start = time.monotonic()
            try:
                result = func(self, *args, **kw)
            except (StopIteration, StopAsyncIteration):
                self.ellapsed += time.monotonic() - start
                #self.print_ellapsed()
                raise
            finally:
                self.measures -= 1
            self.ellapsed += time.monotonic() - start

            return result
        return wrapper

    def print_ellapsed(self):
        name = getattr(self.corofunc, "__name__", "inner_iterator")
        print(f"Ellapsed time in execution of {name}: {self.ellapsed:.05f}s")

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        # WARNING: not parallel execution-safe: fix by
        # keeping "self.ellapsed" in a proper contextvar
        self.ellapsed = 0
        self.measures = 0
        if not isinstance(self.corofunc, async_generator_asend_type):
            self.coro = self.corofunc(*args, **kw)
        else:
            self.coro = self.corofunc
        return self


    def __await__(self):
        return self

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    @measure_ellapsed
    def __next__(self):
        target = self.coro
        if hasattr(target, "__next__"):
            return target.__next__()
        elif hasattr(target, "send"):
            return target.send(None)

    async def athrow(self, exc):
        print(f"Arghh!, got an async-iter-mode {exc}")
        return await self.async_iter.athrow(exc)

    def throw(self, exc):
        print(f"Arghh!, got an {exc}")
        self.coro.throw(exc)

    @measure_ellapsed
    def send(self, arg):
        return self.coro.send(arg)

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    #async def asend(self, value):
        ...

    async def aclose(self):
        return await self.async_iter.close()

    def close(self):
        return self.async_iter.close()

    async def __anext__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "async_iter"):
            self.async_iter = aiter(self.coro)
        self.inner_profiler = ProfileCoro(self.async_iter.__anext__())
        #start = time.monotonic()
        try:
            result = await self.inner_profiler()
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            #self.print_ellapsed()
            raise
        finally:
            self.ellapsed += self.inner_profiler.ellapsed
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<ProfileCoro wrapper for {self.corofunc}>"

@ProfileCoro
async def run():
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
        # yield i
    return 1

@ProfileCoro
async def walk():
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0.05)
        #yield i
    return 3


@ProfileCoro
async def irun():
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
        yield i

@ProfileCoro
async def iwalk():
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0.05)
        yield i


async def main():
    await run()
    run.print_ellapsed()
    await walk()
    walk.print_ellapsed()
    async for _ in irun():
        print(".", end="", flush=True)
    irun.print_ellapsed()
    async for _ in iwalk():
        pass
    iwalk.print_ellapsed()
    return

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Also, sorry that I did not explain what my profiling code does and why the class decorator is like this. If you want some detailng on that, ping me here,  and I should add in some text later.

Comment: I am currently in process of understanding and trying to use your solution. It is worth noting that it works only in 3.10+

Comment: this is probably valid as a proof of concept-  but some work should go in it to measure real code with concurrent tasks. Actually a lot of work, as I just covered the paths actually used in the implementation, so implementing properly the proxies for throw/athrow, measuring exception times, etc... (I ran it on 3.11) .

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a profiler?

[`yappi`](https://github.com/sumerc/yappi) is exceptionally good at profiling, especially `coroutine`s.

Comment: I didn't downvote, I am going to check if this might be applicable for me.
On the other hand, I would love to understand how to interact with generators. I intend to interact with asyncio a lot, and would prefer to be proficient with it over solving problems externally (which might be the only way, and as I mentioned before I will try).

Comment: I didn't down vote, but... the question is about async generators specifically. It would help to note how that relates to coroutines in general and whether yappi works with them.